# How to downgrade the tensorflow version when using google colaboratory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am a noob in tensorflow.
I am getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I know this occurs as tesorflow 2.0 does not support contrib.
i have tried adding the following into the first cell of the online google colab note book. But it did not work.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

Please bear with me as I am completely new to this.

What Can I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first uninstall tensorflow:

`!pip uninstall tensorflow`

And then reinstall the version you want:

`!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5`